# printing multiple lines out of a parsing loop

Tags: bash, parsing, sed

I've written a loop to parse several lines in a file and extract the information I want in a more userfriendly format, but I'm getting duplicates of the strings I'm parsing being printed. I think I'm doing something wrong (and stupid) in my use of `echo | sed` commands, but I just can't see it now.. can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

File to parse looks (abridged) like this:

```
##################################### topd Tree0 - Tree6 #######################################
* Percentage of taxa in common:  100.0%
* Split Distance [differents/possibles]: 0.461538461538462 [ 12 / 26 ]
* Disagreement [ taxa disagree / all taxa ]: [ 9 / 16 ], New Split Distance: 0, Taxa disagree: ( PAUlopT PAKU2 PAKlopT PAUU4 PLTU1 PLTU3 PLTU4 PLTcif PLTlopT )

##################################### topd Tree0 - Tree7 #######################################
* Percentage of taxa in common:  100.0%
* Split Distance [differents/possibles]: 0.538461538461538 [ 14 / 26 ]
* Disagreement [ taxa disagree / all taxa ]: [ 9 / 16 ], New Split Distance: 0, Taxa disagree: ( PAKU2 PAKlopT PAUU4 PAUlopT PLTU1 PLTU2 PLTU3 PLTU4 PLTlopT )

##################################### topd Tree0 - Tree8 #######################################
* Percentage of taxa in common:  100.0%
* Split Distance [differents/possibles]: 0.230769230769231 [ 6 / 26 ]
* Disagreement [ taxa disagree / all taxa ]: [ 4 / 16 ], New Split Distance: 0, Taxa disagree: ( PLTU1 PLTU2 PLTU3 PLTU4 )
```

And I want just the headers and the Taxa disagree (i.e. lines 1 and end of line 4)

But I'm getting this where lines are triplicated (and in some cases giving different taxa lists, but I haven't addressed that problem yet if it's a separate one):

```
Tree0 - Tree6   PAKlopT PAUlopT PLTU1   PLTU2   PLTU3   PLTU4   PLTlopT
Tree0 - Tree6   PAKlopT PAUlopT PLTU1   PLTU2   PLTU3   PLTU4   PLTlopT
Tree0 - Tree6   PAKlopT PAUlopT PLTU1   PLTU2   PLTU3   PLTU4   PLTlopT
Tree0 - Tree6   PAUlopT PAKU2   PAKlopT PAUU4   PLTU1   PLTU3   PLTU4   PLTcif  PLTlopT
Tree0 - Tree6   PAUlopT PAKU2   PAKlopT PAUU4   PLTU1   PLTU3   PLTU4   PLTcif  PLTlopT
Tree0 - Tree7   PAUlopT PAKU2   PAKlopT PAUU4   PLTU1   PLTU3   PLTU4   PLTcif  PLTlopT
Tree0 - Tree7   PAUlopT PAKU2   PAKlopT PAUU4   PLTU1   PLTU3   PLTU4   PLTcif  PLTlopT
Tree0 - Tree7   PAUlopT PAKU2   PAKlopT PAUU4   PLTU1   PLTU3   PLTU4   PLTcif  PLTlopT
Tree0 - Tree7   PAKU2   PAKlopT PAUU4   PAUlopT PLTU1   PLTU2   PLTU3   PLTU4   PLTlopT
Tree0 - Tree7   PAKU2   PAKlopT PAUU4   PAUlopT PLTU1   PLTU2   PLTU3   PLTU4   PLTlopT
Tree0 - Tree8   PAKU2   PAKlopT PAUU4   PAUlopT PLTU1   PLTU2   PLTU3   PLTU4   PLTlopT
Tree0 - Tree8   PAKU2   PAKlopT PAUU4   PAUlopT PLTU1   PLTU2   PLTU3   PLTU4   PLTlopT
Tree0 - Tree8   PAKU2   PAKlopT PAUU4   PAUlopT PLTU1   PLTU2   PLTU3   PLTU4   PLTlopT
Tree0 - Tree8   PLTU1   PLTU2   PLTU3   PLTU4
Tree0 - Tree8   PLTU1   PLTU2   PLTU3   PLTU4
```

and this is the code I've written (I doubt it's particularly elegant or efficient)

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$1"
###

while read LINE ;
do
 if [[ $LINE == "#"* ]] 
  then
    header=$(echo $LINE | sed 's/\#//g' | sed 's/\ topd\ //g')
 fi
 if [[ $LINE == "* Disagreement"* ]] ;
  then
   taxa=$(echo $LINE | sed 's/.*(\(\ .*\ \))/\1/' | grep "^ " |sed 's/\ /\t/g')
 fi

echo "$header""$taxa"

done < $file
```

EDIT:

The actual file I'm trying to process:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz_H3y-7pX9FX0lZTWNBdlpIQmc

Comment: I'd suggest using a text processing language like awk or sed instead of bash.

Comment: Your logic is wrong in your script: you are printing a line for every line you process. You want to print only after you processed a "* Disagreement" line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` probably isn't the best language for this, but using `bash` regular-expression matching will make it much simpler.

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$1"
###

header_regex='# topd (.*) #'
taxa_regex='Taxa disagree: \((.*)\)'
while read line; do
  if [[ $line =~ $header_regex ]]; then
    header=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  elif [[ $line =~ $taxa_regex ]]; then
    taxa=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo "$header $taxa"
  fi    
done < "$file"
```

Comment: You may want to escape those `#`.

Comment: Yup, for some reason I thought you couldn't start a comment inside `[[`.

Comment: I think you have to escape spaces as well. Might be better to put the regex in a var.

Comment: I probably missed some; this is why it's better to just store the regex in a variable, where you can quote the whole thing, then expand it unquoted inside the conditional command.

Comment: I'm getting `if [[ $line =~ \#\ topd (.*) \# ]]; then` syntax errors. Complaining about the "(." for some reason? EDIT: We have a winner. That's worked really nicely thanks. Where was my error in my loop exactly?

Comment: That's caused by the unescaped space after `topd` that 123 alluded to. Use the new version, where I store the regular expressions in parameters to ease quoting everything. (You can't quote the regular expression as a whole directly after `=~`, because it is treated as a literal string match in that case.)

Comment: Perhaps I spoke to soon... I seem to be getting replicated lines now on closer inspection. I'll provide the actual files in my question if someone wouldn't mind checking on their machines.

Comment: Oh, the `echo` should only be performed after matching a `Taxa disagree` line, not on every line.

Comment: Not using `IFS=` and `-r` in a `while read` loop (e.g. `while IFS= read -r line; do`) is like not quoting your variables - you should only do it if you have a specific purpose in mind and fully understand all the implications. Since shell is not designed to process text you frequently have to add extra constructs to get intuitive behavior. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it purely with `sed`. I propose two steps:

```
sed -n -e 's/#* \(.*\) #*$/\1/p' -e 's/.*( \(.*\) )$/\1/p' < file.txt
```

That leaves you with an output like this:

```
topd Tree0 - Tree6
PAUlopT PAKU2 PAKlopT PAUU4 PLTU1 PLTU3 PLTU4 PLTcif PLTlopT
topd Tree0 - Tree7
PAKU2 PAKlopT PAUU4 PAUlopT PLTU1 PLTU2 PLTU3 PLTU4 PLTlopT
topd Tree0 - Tree8
```

In a second step you have to merge the pairs of lines, which can also be done with `sed`, just by piping the previous output:

```
... | sed 'N;s/\n/\t/'
```

Perhaps the second step can somehow be integrated into the first one, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Yeah I struggled with multiple regexs in sed (never really done it before). This solution gets close, but what I'm ultimately after is a tab delimited line for each tree comparison. This leaves all the ###'s behind and over 2 lines.

Comment: Yep great thanks. The following ultimately gives me what I would be looking for, in an albeit lengthy one-liner: `sed -n -e 's/#* \(.*\) #*$/\1/p' -e 's/.*( \(.*\) )$/\1/p' < AllvsSpecies_short.txt | sed 'N;s/\n/\t/' | cut -d ' ' -f 1 --complement`

Answer (score 1):

Shell is not for manipulating text, it's for sequencing calls to tools, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice.

The right way to do what you want in UNIX is to use the standard UNIX general purpose text manipulation tool awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/####/ { hdr = $3 " - " $5 }
/Disagreement/ { gsub(/.*\( *| *\).*/,""); print hdr, $0 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Tree0 - Tree6 PAUlopT PAKU2 PAKlopT PAUU4 PLTU1 PLTU3 PLTU4 PLTcif PLTlopT
Tree0 - Tree7 PAKU2 PAKlopT PAUU4 PAUlopT PLTU1 PLTU2 PLTU3 PLTU4 PLTlopT
Tree0 - Tree8 PLTU1 PLTU2 PLTU3 PLTU4
```